# php DateTime object does not give me errors for an invalid date input?

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.4

Why php DateTime object does not give me errors for an invalid date input? For instance,

```
$date_test = '13-10-31';

$datetime = new DateTime();
$date = $datetime->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_test);
$date_errors = $datetime->getLastErrors();
print_r($date_errors);
```

result,

```
Array
(
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I have set the date format to be 'Y-m-d' which is yyyy-mm-dd so '13-10-31' should be an error input isn't?

**EDIT**

if I change this line `$datetime->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_test);` to

```
$datetime->createFromFormat('YY-m-d', $date_test);
```

I will get an error no matter what I input. For instance,

```
$date_test = '2013-10-31';
```

result,

```
Array
(
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 2
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [4] => Unexpected data found.
            [10] => Data missing
        )

)
```

Why!??

Comment: What does `$date` look like? And how is that line (`$date = $datetime->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_test);`) doing anything if you're not using `$date`?

Comment: 10=October having 31 days is still valid.

Comment: As @Corrupt answered, 13 is translated as 13AD(Anno Domini). So very much of valid dates.

Comment: @Lenin Might I add, the year 13 is valid as well, although most of the people that lived that year have already died.

Comment: 'DateTime::createFromFormat()' is a static function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is a valid date, however your code is incorrect in that [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is a static function as is [`getLastErrors()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php). Your example code should be:-

```
$date_test = '13-10-31';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_test);
$date_errors = \DateTime::getLastErrors();
print_r($date_errors);
```

However, there will still be no errors as the 31st October 13 (13-10-31) is a valid date. When you provide `'13'` as the year, DateTime casts it to an integer, `13`, therefore, it is a valid year.

If you want to discard double digit years as invalid, then you will have to write your own validation functions.

I would recommend a thorough read of the [PHP Date and Time extensions documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.calendar.php)

Comment: @lauthiamkok Of course it doesn't! As I clearly stated in my answer 13-10-31 __is a valid date__.

Answer (score 5):

`echo $date->format('d-m-Y')` showed `31-10-0013`, so looks like php threating your date as normal.

---

**UPDv1:**

This is not mentioned in [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Still if you look into `echo $date->format('U');` it will give you a negative timestamp.

Since **PHPv5.3.0** this feature is confirmed, according to [*3v4l test*](http://3v4l.org/CTOAn).

Comment: It's interesting that on my windows system `$date->getTimestamp()` returns false, while `$date->format('U')` gives the expected negative timestamp. It works fine on my linux box though and [here](http://3v4l.org/EKp1a). Strange

Comment: Your test is calling `createFromFormat()` in a non-static way.

Answer (score 0):

this is not because of the date inputted but by the incorrect defination of Year parameter.

Comment: Please check here for complete date formats        http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Did you expect years to be of leading zero for less than 4digits? @lauthiamkok

Comment: i was commenting about your second edit. i.e $datetime->createFromFormat('YY-m-d', $date_test);
I will get an error no matter what I input. For instance, in case you thought it otherwise.